# How can i embed qr code scanner to my mobile ordering app?

Tags: xamarin-studio

i want to make my mobile ordering app more easy to use by having a qr code scanner which will be used to scan QR Codes, and after scanning, the output of the scan will be the input in the order form of my app.

Comment: Please show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: I already tried APK Tool, APK Edit and APK Easy Manager but it all doesn't work out.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the ZXing.Net component available either as a Xamarin Component or as a NuGet package.

Cheers,
Tristan